# RavenDb in ram and 404 Not found errors

Tags: ravendb

I'm tring to use a full in-memory RavenDB (version 2.5.2996) to run some integration tests.
I started the RavenDB server using the following command:

```
    Raven.Server.exe --ram --debug
```

The server started correctly.
The integration tests stuck and I get a lot of errors in the RavenDB debug console:

```
    Request #143: GET - o ms - <database name> - 404 - /indexes/Raven/DocumentByEntityName?definition=yes
```

Using a normal RavenDB instance (not in memory), the integration tests pass.
I tried to search in the RavenDB documentation for some clues but I didn't find anything. Anyone can help me to understand why it is not working?

Comment: This might be happening because you are using an in memory instance that isn't used for some time, so it is closed (and all the data is lost).
Do you have a db per test, or shared db for all tests?

Comment: @AyendeRahien We are using a normal local instance of RavenDB (I mean executing the Raven.Server.exe executable) to run some integration tests for our system. Each integration test delete the previous database and create a new database. I simply replaced the local normal instance with a full in memory instance (using the --ram option). I started the database server and I started the integration tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--ram` options is for the system database, you need to specify that each db is also running in memory by setting `Raven/RunInMemory = true` when you create the db.

Comment: Can you explain me why it is not done by default (by design) when it detects that it is a "in memory" (ram) server instance. It makes no senses to have to set it manually if you want to use "In memory" in your local tests/dev and then a real DB (not in memory) for release.

Comment: That is an issue with the way we behave, but it will only be fixed in 4.0